# Keeping two staging environments - one for hotfixes and another for new release

Tags: git

I am facing a problem with git branching for new releases and hotfix changes. Currently, I have

1. a master branch tagged with release versions.
2. a development  branch checked out from the latest master branch and
   where new features are merged into and
3. a staging branch where client tests the new utilities. Once 
   successful, the code of the staging branch is merged into master
   with a new release tag.

There is no production or release branch as of now as the current head of master branch points to a new release and every commit in the master is basically a release.

Now suppose I am working on a new release, and the code is already in the staging environment with bug fixes going on.

Suddenly there comes a new requirement for the code which is currently running in production (basically a hotfix). So, I had to switch to my latest master, do the necessary changes and set it to the staging environment. But the staging environment is already populated with code for the new release which is yet to come.

So, should I have two different staging environments,

1. one for the new release and
2. the other for hotfixes

But reading through the blogs and documents on git, I did not find anyone doing so.

How should I proceed?

Comment: It sounds like you need `git stash`

Comment: Git stash will only stash your uncommitted changes. There is no such thing here.

Comment: What does staging environment mean in this case?

Comment: It seems to me you have answered your own question: you want multiple staging environments. (You might want *more* than two, e.g., one for *every* client, so that if you have six clients, you have six for-client-to-test staging branches, or even twelve such: one for Client A to test what your development group plan to sell them next month, and another for Client A to test what your support group plan to send them tomorrow; two for Client B; and so on.)